# Efficient Algorithm for calculating Edge Connectedness?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

What I would like to know is if there is any literature that I could read for algorithms to determine the edge connectedness of all edges in a given graph.

The edge connectedness of a given edge (as understood by me) is the number of shortest paths (between diff nodes) that pass through a given edge. That is, if we were to travel from every node to every other node, how many times would we pass through a given edge.

Any help/resource would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to improve shortest path query time with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called edge betweennesss as far as I know. Here is a paper for a good algorithm for vertex betweenness, it can be easily generalized to edge betweenness:

Brandes, Ulrik (2001). "A faster algorithm for betweenness centrality" (PDF). Journal of Mathematical Sociology 25: 163–177
http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-fabc-01.pdf

Comment: +1 for giving the correct name (I also suspected that this is the same as Edge Betweenness Centrality measure)

Answer (score 0):

Use Dijkstra algortihm to find the shortest path. Use this algorithm repeatedly to determine the shortest paths of all pairs of nodes. Now you can simply sum up the occurence of each edge in each path.

Comment: shortest path will ignore some edges if there exists another path with shorter distance